# Unable to call Spring Boot API inside Ubuntu WSL2 at localhost:8080 using Postman

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu, postman, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am having trouble calling and posting to an API build with Spring Boot inside a WSL2 Ubuntu environment. I can run the project and it gets initialized at port 8080 as shown in the logs:

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.4)

2022-10-14 16:18:11.033  INFO 32139 --- [           main] com.example.demo3.Demo3Application       : Starting Demo3Application using Java 17.0.4 on LCE50469 with PID 32139 (/home/joschenk/ModelAPI/target/classes started by joschenk in /home/joschenk/ModelAPI)
2022-10-14 16:18:11.036  INFO 32139 --- [           main] com.example.demo3.Demo3Application       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-10-14 16:18:11.716  INFO 32139 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-10-14 16:18:11.722  INFO 32139 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-10-14 16:18:11.722  INFO 32139 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-10-14 16:18:11.779  INFO 32139 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-10-14 16:18:11.779  INFO 32139 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 703 ms
2022-10-14 16:18:12.005  INFO 32139 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-10-14 16:18:12.012  INFO 32139 --- [           main] com.example.demo3.Demo3Application       : Started Demo3Application in 1.227 seconds (JVM running for 1.655)
```

When now trying to Post to the API using Postman with

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/model
```

I am getting the following response:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 846f27f6-f2e6-4d0f-9554-3fdb3f352bc9
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Can someone help here? Thanks!**

Comment: Have you checked firewall configurations? https://visualgdb.com/documentation/wsl2/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by running a wsl2 kernel update inside the Windows Powershell. I then rebooted everything and now it works.

```
wsl --update
wsl --shutdown
```